# Excel - Copy data if it's in certain hour

Tags: excel, time, average

I have a list of data for every hour in every day for the last month.
I want to average the data from the whole month for every specific hour.

For example:

```
       Time                        Data      Data 2
17/12/2015 14:00:00                 15        30
17/12/2015 15:00:00                 30        40
18/12/2015 14:00:00                 20        15
21/12/2015 15:00:00                 31        41
```

I want to extract all of the values of 14:00 and 15:00 and average them.

```
      Time                 AverageData      AverageData 2
     14:00                     17.5             22.5
     15:00                     30.5             40.5
```

I need to do it for every hour of the day, I thought about doing it in two stages:
First, extract all the values for the same hour and then do the average.

Any suggestions?
Thank you

Comment: You could also get the same result easily with a Pivot Table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would have a helper column calculating the time only from the datetime values. So we can use `AVERAGEIF`.

The `ROUND` is needed avoiding issues with floating point precision.

Example:

[image]

Formulas:

`D2` downwards:

```
=ROUND(A2-INT(A2),10)
```

`G2` downwards and to left:

```
=AVERAGEIF($D:$D,ROUND($F2,10),B:B)
```

Without a helper column you could use in `G2` downwards and to left:

```
{=AVERAGE(IF(ROUND($A$2:$A$100-INT($A$2:$A$100),10)=ROUND($F2,10),B$2:B$100))}
```

as an array formula.

But this will be of bad performance if used in much single cells.

**Second approach:**

If only the hour shall match, not the whole time, get only the hour from the datetime value in column `A` in the helper column `D`:

Formulas:

`D2` downwards:

```
=HOUR(A2)
```

`G2` downwards and to left:

```
=AVERAGEIF($D:$D,HOUR($F2),B:B)
```

Without a helper column you could use in `G2` downwards and to left:

```
{=AVERAGE(IF(HOUR($A$2:$A$100)=HOUR($F2),B$2:B$100))}
```

as an array formula.

Comment: I don't know why, but i'm getting #DIV/0 error on certain hours :(

Comment: Examples please. Maybe the times don't match exactly. Try `ROUND` less than 10 digits. Or if only the hour shall match, then try my second approach.

Comment: Oh, and of course you get `#DIV/0!` if you try calculating the average of values from a time which does not exist in column `A`. Then there are no values for calculating the average. What shall the average of no values be?

Answer (score 0):

If doing it by formula, you are right, I don't think you can do it directly using AVERAGEIFS (unless you set up a helper column with the hours in it), so need to do something like this:-

```
=SUM(B$2:B$5*(HOUR($A$2:$A$5)=$E2))/SUM(--(HOUR($A$2:$A$5)=$E2))
```

I'm assuming that E2 contains the hour that you want to select and your data is in the first three columns.

This is an array formula and must be entered with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>

[image]